# How can I get the declaration value in Styles using xpath?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufY5J.png)

There are no tags that indicate the background color of the element that I need to get.
Is there a way to get the value in "Styles" tab in the screenshot I provided?

Comment: Does this link help: http://www.martinbroadhurst.com/how-to-get-the-style-of-an-element-in-selenium.html

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.